# XSL Holding incremented Value

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping

Knowing that you cannot increment a value if it meets a certain condition what is the approach for this logic then.

```
<xsl:for-each select="(//node())">

if(node-name==test1)
<tag>value of (How many tag elements already exists)</tag>

if(node-name==test2)
<tag>value of (How many tag elements already exists)</tag>

if(node-name==test3)
<tag>value of (How many tag elements already exists)</tag>
</xsl:for-each>
```

So if test3 was only true the value would be 1 for the tag value. This is also true if only one of the three tests were true.

```
<tag>1</tag>
```

If all were true then it would go

```
<tag>1</tag>
<tag>2</tag>
<tag>3</tag>
```

If two were true there would only be 2 tags and the 1 and 2 would be the values for them.

```
<tag>1</tag>
<tag>2</tag>
```

Comment: I can't figure out what your question is.

Comment: The value in tag. How do I increment that based off previous if conditions.

Comment: Still no clue. I suggest you post a small example of the input and the expected output, and explain the required logic in words, not in some cryptic pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to reverse-engineer a requirement from incorrect code (or pseudo-code). In your code the processing of an input set results in the creation of a number of "tag elements" (awkward terminology for "element nodes with local name 'tag'"). The number of these that "already exist" at any point is unpredictable, since it depends entirely on order of execution, which isn't defined by the spec. But let's imagine that this wasn't an xsl:for-each, but some kind of procedural, sequential for-each in which the items were guaranteed to be processed one-by-one in order. If that's the semantics you had in mind for your pseudocode, then you need recursion:

```
<xsl:template name="process-items">
  <xsl:param name="items"/>
  <xsl:param name="tags-created"/>
  <xsl:variable name="head" select="$items[1]"/>
  <xsl:variable name="tail" select="$items[position() > 1]"/>
  <xsl:if test="$head">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::tag1 or self::tag2">
        <tag><xsl:value-of select="$tags-created"/></tag>
        <xsl:call-template name="process-items">
          <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$tail"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="tags-created select="$tags-created+1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="process-items">
          <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$tail"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="tags-created select="$tags-created"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And then call this with initial parameters `//node()` and `0`.

In 2.0 you can do the same thing with a recursive function, which is the same principle but vastly less verbose, and in 3.0 you can use xsl:iterate.